# Round table combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Sorry if this is a horrible format to read(first time using this site!).

Your friends A, B, C and D are going to sit right next to eachother around a round table at your birthdayparty. You do not want any of them to wear the same color of shirt this day. Therefore you have made an overview of your friends sitting  by the round table including the colors of all their shirts.

(colors are not in red,blue,green, but in 1,2,3....100)

Given this order:

1.Friend A has 3 shirts with colors 1,2 and 3.

2.Friend B has 2 shirts with colors 3 and 4.

3.Friend C has 1 shirt with color 3.

4.Friend D has 1 shirt with color 1.

Yes, friend A sits right next to friend D.

How do i mathematically(i.e. with combinations, faculty, etc) prove that there are in this case 2 dressing combinations so that none of them wear a shirt with the same color? Will the same way of a "working" solution work if we change the numbers around. For instance:

1. Friend A has 1 shirt with colors 1.
2. Friend B has 3 shirts with colors 1,2 and 3.
3. Friend C has 2 shirt with color 2,3.
4. Friend D has 1 shirt with color 1.

Will give us 0 dressing combinations?

Comment: Does it have any relevance for the problem who sits next to whom?

Comment: Seems to be a bit of a mix of problems (which is fine, but needs to be clear). I'm not sure how the seating and the shirt colours are related if at all. On the given shirt availability, there is only one option for shirts on the first specification, and none for the second.

Comment: @HenningMakholm is it ok if I send you the task in mail(it's written in norwegian) ?

Comment: @HenningMakholm sent it to your e-mail, please consider reading it as it originally is combinatorics meant for CS :)

Comment: @Heinrich: Unfortunately the email address on my profile is currently out of service due to a server failure, so I won't see it. :-(

Comment: @HenningMakholm any other way of contacting you, facebook, etc?

Comment: @HenningMakholm sende deg oppgåven på facebook.

Answer (score 0):

The friends-with-shirts problem is isomorphic to a problem I solved (for feasibility, not for combination counts) on another site concerning marriages, where each boy knows some girls willing to marry him. The additional condition was that any group of $n$ boys knows at least $n$ girls between them - this is obviously necessary to arrange a full set of monogamous marriages but also turns out to be sufficient (ignoring, in the usual way, real-world complications).

So for the feasibility of dressing all friends in different shirts (without borrowing etc), you need only have that there is no group of friends that have fewer shirts of different colours between them than friends in that group. In the second case, clearly A and D form a group that fails, as indeed does the full set {A,B,C,D}.

For combination counts I'm not sure there is any way bar brute force enumeration.